# bootstrap checkbox switch when off hide div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap checkbox switch on my site.

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

when the switch is switched to off I would like to hide the div class "name-number-form

I noticed however, that when the switch is switched on and off, the checked does not disappear when its off. If that was the case I would have done this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.switch-on input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.name-number-form').show();
    } else {
        $('.name-number-form').hide();
    }
});
});
```

but when I switch to off the checked does not disappear so I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.switch-on').change(function(){
    if($(this).is('.switch-on')){
        $('.name-number-form').show();
    } else {
        $('.name-number-form').hide();
    }
});
});
```

no luck

I made an alert to see if the attribute is working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.switch-on').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
    alert('this is switch ' + $(this).attr('switch-id'));
    var $el = $(data.el)
            , value = data.value;
    if(value){//this is true if the switch is on
        $('.name-number-form').show();
    }else{
        $('.name-number-form').hide();
    }
});
});
```

i created a unique attribute for the name-number-form too called data-name-number-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To catch the change of the switch you need to assign a callback to the `switch-change` event. 
For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/NuE7X/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.switch-on').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
        var $el = $(data.el)
          , value = data.value;
        if(value){//this is true if the switch is on
           $('.name-number-form').show();
        }else{
           $('.name-number-form').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT - response to comments**
If you want to start in `off` state and have the div hidden, you can modify html as follows,

```
<div class="make-switch switch-on">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="name-number-form" style="display:none">this is name number form</div>
```

**EDIT2 - response to comments**
If you have multiple switches and associated `name-number-form` you could use jQuery `next` method to select the next sibbling with the specified selector. For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/V7gjM/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.switch-on').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {

        var $el = $(data.el),
            value = data.value;
        if (value) { //this is true if the switch is on
            $(this).next('.name-number-form').show();
        } else {
            $(this).next('.name-number-form').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that works great thank you.. I would like though, to start at off and hidden. How might I do that?

Comment: One other quick question: I need to associate the slider with the name-number-form because I have multiple bootstrap sliders on one page that hide a name-number-form. I created a unique class for each name-number-form and for each slider. I am just not sure how to call the attribute value.. see my question for more notes

Comment: @anmaree updated the answer. However if you really need to use id related attributes then you will need to set an attribute to both `switch-on` element and `name-number-form` with the same id (e.g. `<div class="make-switch switch-on" data-switch=1>` and `<div class="name-number-form" style="display:none" data-switch=1>`), in order to associate them and call your selectors accordingly. In js you would call something like `$('.name-number-form[data-switch='+$(this).data("switch")+']').show();`

Comment: You are amazing thank you for all your help. I have learned a lot!